# Add menu links to custom generated menu

Tags: 8, entities, hooks, navigation

I am working on a custom Drupal 8 module which generates a menu. Refer [Create a new Menu in Drupal 8 programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/251663/79123) for details.

I have the menu now, but when I try to add custom menu links to it, following [add a menu link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-menu-link), somehow it's not getting added to that custom menu.

Another weird thing is that the links are getting added to the wrong menu, i.e. they show under `User Account Management` menu.

The only reason I can think of is, when I install the module, Drupal tries to create the menu link first, before it has created custom menu. As the custom menu is not there yet, it tries to add the menu links to another menu. Is that right?

Here is my code, if that helps:

```
// system.menu.aeauth.yml // This creates the new menu on module install

langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: aeauth
label: 'AE Authentication Links'
description: 'Links related to AE Authentication'
locked: true
```

---

```
// ae.links.menu.yml // This adds menu links to menus

ae.admin_settings:
  route_name: ae.adminForm
  title: 'AE Configuration'
  description: 'Configure AE for your website'
  parent: system.admin_config_system

ae.register:
  title: 'Register'
  description: 'Register using AE Connect'
  parent: aeauth
  route_name: ae.regroute

ae.login:
  title: 'Login'
  description: 'Login using AE Connect'
  parent: aeauth
  route_name: ae.loginroute
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not specifying what menu your links belong to. Instead you are setting the parent, but I think the parent doesn't exist in your cast. This works for me:

**custom_module/system.menu.my-custom-menu.yml:**

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: my-custom-menu
label: 'My Custom Menu'
description: ''
locked: true
```

**custom_module/config/install/custom_module.links.menu.yml:**

```
custom_module.custom_link:
  title: 'My Custom Link'
  weight: -10
  route_name: custom_module.custom_route
  menu_name: 'my-custom-menu'
```